# When comparing two physical quantities, should units be specified only after the second?

Tags: measuring-units

I am writing an academic report. I am comparing to values in the text of the report: 1.011 Hz and 0.990 Hz.

Is it correct to write:

"1.011 compared to 0.990 Hz"

or

"1.011 Hz compared to 0.990 Hz"

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow scientific type documentation grade, you should repeat the unit, according to the NIST

See point 12 from http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html

> It is clear to which unit symbol a numerical value belongs and which
>   mathematical operation applies to the value of a quantity.
>
> proper:
>
> - 35 cm x 48 cm
> - 1 MHz to 10 MHz or (1 to 10) MHz
> - 20 °C to 30 °C or (20 to 30) °C
> - 123 g ± 2 g or (123 ± 2) g
> - 70 % ± 5 % or (70 ± 5) %
>
>   improper:
> - 35 x 48 cm